# session.dirty is empty despite modified object

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I'm following the official tutorials and have run into a problem: Even though I changed an object, the `session.dirty` call gives me an empty list. I'm not sure what's causing it. Could it be that the behavior of `session.dirty` is undefined in some cases?

Here's the code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
Base = declarative_base()

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id       = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name     = Column(String)
    fullname = Column(String)
    password = Column(String)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "User<name={}, fullname={}, password={}>".format(self.name, self.fullname, self.password)

# Create all tables
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

ed_user = User(name='ed', fullname='Ed Jones', password='edspassword')
session.add(ed_user)
session.add_all([
    User(name='wendy', fullname='Wendy Williams', password='foobar'),
    User(name='mary', fullname='Mary Contrary', password='xxg527'),
    User(name='fred', fullname='Fred Flinstone', password='blah')
])
ed_user.password = 'f8s7ccs'
print(session.dirty) # Note: session.dirty without print does nothing
```

And the output:

```
2016-01-26 07:57:43,149 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test plain returns' AS VARCHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2016-01-26 07:57:43,149 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2016-01-26 07:57:43,150 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test unicode returns' AS VARCHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2016-01-26 07:57:43,150 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2016-01-26 07:57:43,151 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine PRAGMA table_info("users")
2016-01-26 07:57:43,151 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2016-01-26 07:57:43,152 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine 
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    name VARCHAR, 
    fullname VARCHAR, 
    password VARCHAR, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)


2016-01-26 07:57:43,152 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2016-01-26 07:57:43,152 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
IdentitySet([])
```

Answer (score 2):

All right, so I figured it out myself. I was getting nothing in `session.dirty` because there was no commit yet to compare against. In fact, the object for Ed was visible in `session.new`. So when I did a `session.commit()` and then changed Ed, the object was available in `session.dirty`.